# How to get a home base airport in the UAE?

Tags: airport

How can you get a permanent home base airport in the United Arab Emirates, if your company is registered in different country?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you asking how an airline based outside the UAE could use the UAE as its base/hub?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to know.